# C array sorting ignoring special characters

Tags: c, sorting

```
char temp[size];
int b, z;
for (b = 0; b < size; b++) {
    for (z = 0; z < size; z++) {
        if (strcmp(processNames[b], processNames[z]) < 0) {
            strcpy(temp, processNames[b]);
            strcpy(processNames[b], processNames[z]);
            strcpy(processNames[z], temp);
        }         
    }
}
```

I'm sorting a list of `char ** processNames;`

I want it to sort like this:

```
abc 
bee
george
(sally)
saw
thomas
zebra
```

However, it is sorting it like this:

```
(sally)
abc 
bee
george
saw
thomas
zebra
```

Thanks, I'm not sure how to negate the special characters and only sort on alphabet. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. It's because of `(` ascii code. It is less than ascii code of little alphabets. You should consider it in your code.

Comment: So before the strcmp? And if its less just skip that iteration?

Comment: yes. you should skip from specific characters before `strcmp`.

Comment: The sort loop isn't right either.  The inner loop should start at `b+1`, not zero.

Comment: You can no longer use `strcmp()`; you have to devise your own function (or find one that will work for you).  What should you do with digits?  What should happen to O'Malley and Oman and Omaha?  What about spaces?  What about multiple consecutive spaces?  Tabs?  Capital letters vs lower case?

Comment: Also note that once you fix the inner loop to start at `b+1`, you will need to reverse the comparison (the current code is basically swapping everything twice, since the loop bounds are wrong).  Half of the current swaps are in the wrong order as it is now.

Comment: @TomKarzes So fix the for loop to b=1? And change the strcmp to > 0?

Comment: @TrevorGood Change the inner loop, the `z` loop, to begin at `b+1` rather than `0`.  I already said that, didn't I?  And yes, I believe you'll need to reverse your comparison once you do that, but that will be clear the first time you test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-process the string and use `strcmp` to compare the processed string:

```
// Inside the two-layer for loop
char newb[size], newz[size];
int ib, iz, tb = 0, tz = 0;
for (ib = 0; processNames[b][ib] != '\0'; ib++){
    if (isalpha(processNames[b][ib])) {
        newb[tb++] = processNames[b][ib];
    }
}
newb[tb] = 0;
for (iz = 0; processNames[z][iz] != '\0'; iz++){
    if (isalpha(processNames[z][iz])) {
        newz[tz++] = processNames[z][iz];
    }
}
newz[tz] = 0;

if (strcmp(newb, newz)) {
    // swap the ORIGINAL string here
}
```

The above code is what I came up with at first. It is very inefficient and is not recommended. Alternatively, you can write your own `mystrcmp()` implementation:

```
int mystrcmp(const char* a, const char *b){
    while (*a && *b) {
        while (*a && !isalpha(*a)) a++;
        while (*b && !isalpha(*b)) b++;
        if (*a - *b) return *a - *b;
        a++, b++;
    }
    return *a - *b;
}
```

Comment: Fully copying (with filtering) both strings every time there is a comparison to do is a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: I second @EricPostpischil; you could use this too, but it would need a "Schwartzian transform"

Comment: The `mystrcmp()` code looks fine.  The earlier code is very heavy, not least because the strings could both be 2 KiB long, and they'd be fully transformed, but then the first characters would be different and 99.9% of the work would be wasted.

Answer (score 2):

“Sorting” means “putting things in order.” What order? The order is defined by some *thing* that tells us which of two items goes first.

In your code, you are using `strcmp` to decide which item goes first. That is the *thing* that decides the order. Since `strcmp` is giving an order you do not want, you need another function. In this case, you have to write your own function.

Your function should take two strings (via pointers to `char`), examine the strings, and return a value to indicate whether the first string should be before or after the second string (or whether they are equal).

Since this is likely a class assignment, I will leave it to you to ponder the necessary comparison function.

#### Alternative

There is an alternative method which is likely to be used in professionally deployed code, in suitable situations. I recommend the above because it is suitable for a class assignment—it addresses the key principle this assignment seems to target.

The alternative is to preprocess all the list items before doing the sort. Since you want to sort on the non-special characters of the names, you would augment the list by creating copies of the names with the special characters removed. These new versions would be your “sort keys”—they would be the values you use to decide order instead of the original names. You could compare them with `strcmp`.

This method requires allocating new memory for the new versions of the names, managing both the keys and the names while you sort them, and releasing the memory after the sort. It requires some overhead before you start the sort. However, if there are a very large number of things to sort with a considerable number of special characters, then doing the extra work up front can result in better performance overall.

(Again, I mention this only for completeness. It is likely not useful in a class assignment of this sort, just something computer science students should learn over time.)

#### Bonus Notes

You say you are sorting an array of `char **ProcessNames`. In this case, it is probably not necessary to move the strings themselves with `strcpy`. Instead, you can simply move the pointers to the strings. E.g., if you want to swap `ProcessNames[4]` and `ProcessNames[7]`, just make a copy of the pointer that is `ProcessNames[4]`, set `ProcessNames[4]` to be the pointer that is `ProcessNames[7]`, and set `ProcessNames[7]` to be the temporary copy you made. This is generally faster than moving strings.

As others note, starting your `z` loop with `z = 0` is probably not a good idea. You likely want `z = b+1`.

Your code uses `size` for the size of the string buffer (`char temp[size]`) and for the size of the `ProcessNames` array (`for (b = 0; b < size; b++)`). It is unlikely the number of strings to be sorted is the same as the maximum length of the strings. You should be sure to use the correct size in each instance.

Comment: There’s the standard function `strxfrm()` which is, I suspect, one of the least used functions in C.  It isn’t directly useful, but the concept is standardized.